# MySQL localhost connection refused

Tags: mysql, 20.04, connection, localhost, mysql-workbench

When I try to connect to localhost I get this error message 
[08001] Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused).

it's on ubuntu 20.04 and I'm using Jetbrains' datagrip.

Comment: What is the address of your localhost?  Also, what pot are you using for your MySQL server?

Comment: I use port 3306 and the address of my localhost is 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the server? `sudo service mysql restart` or `sudo service mysql stop`
`sudo service mysql start`

Comment: when i tries to start it says "Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found".

Comment: I just installed mysql with the command sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server mysql-client but now I have this problem The specified database user/password combination is rejected: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost).